# Can you help me fix the exception/error message handling in my control architecture script?

Tags: php, oop, uncaught-exception

Can you help me fix the exception/error message handling in my control architecture script?

First, let me post the actual script...

*Note: some of the code's indentation is a bit off, but I am uncertain how to fix it.  I apologize.*

```
class FrontController extends ActionController {

//Declaring variable(s)
private static $instance;
protected $controller;

//Class construct method
public function __construct() {}

//Starts new instance of this class with a singleton pattern
public static function getInstance() {
    if(!self::$instance) {
        self::$instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

public function dispatch($throwExceptions = false) {

    /* Checks for the GET variables $module and $action, and, if present,
     * strips them down with a regular expression function with a white
     * list of allowed characters, removing anything that is not a letter,
     * number, underscore or hyphen.
     */
    $regex  = '/[^-_A-z0-9]+/';
    $module = isset($_GET['module']) ? preg_replace($regex, '', $_GET['module']) : 'home';
    $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? preg_replace($regex, '', $_GET['action']) : 'frontpage';

    /* Generates Actions class filename (example: HomeActions) and path to
     * that class (example: home/HomeActions.php), checks if $file is a
     * valid file, and then, if so, requires that file.
     */
    $class = ucfirst($module) . 'Actions';
    $file  = $this->pageDir . '/' . $module . '/' . $class . '.php';

    if (!is_file($file)) {
        throw new FrontControllerException('Page not found!');
    }

    require_once $file;

    /* Creates a new instance of the Actions class (example: $controller
     * = new HomeActions();), and passes the registry variable to the
     * ActionController class.
     */
    $controller = new $class();
    $controller->setRegistry($this->registry);

    try {
        //Trys the setModule method in the ActionController class
        $controller->setModule($module);

        /* The ActionController dispatchAction method checks if the method
         * exists, then runs the displayView function in the
         * ActionController class.
         */    
        $controller->dispatchAction($action);
    }
    catch(Exception $error) {

        /* An exception has occurred, and will be displayed if
         * $throwExceptions is set to true.
         */
        if($throwExceptions) {
            echo $error->errorMessage($error); //Full exception echoed
        } else {
            echo $error->errorMessage(null); //Simple error messaged echoed
        }
    }
}
}

abstract class ActionController {

//Declaring variable(s)
protected $registry;
protected $module;
protected $registryItems = array();

//Class construct method
public function __construct(){}

public function setRegistry($registry) {

    //Sets the registry object
    $this->registry = $registry;

    /* Once the registry is loaded, the controller root directory path is
     * set from the registry.  This path is needed for the controller
     * classes to work properly.
     */
    $this->setPageDir();
}

//Sets the controller root directory from the value stored in the registry
public function setPageDir() {
    $this->pageDir = $this->registry->get('pageDir');
}

//Sets the module
public function setModule($module) {
    $this->module = $module;
}

//Gets the module
public function getModule() {
    return $this->module;
}

/* Checks for actionMethod in the Actions class (example: doFrontpage()
 * within home/HomeActions.php) with the method_exists function and, if
 * present, the actionMethod and displayView functions are executed.
 */  
public function dispatchAction($action) {
    $actionMethod = 'do' . ucfirst($action);
    if (!method_exists($this, $actionMethod)) {
        throw new FrontControllerException('Page not found!');
    }
    $this->$actionMethod();
    $this->displayView($action);
}

public function displayView($action) {
    if (!is_file($this->pageDir . '/' . $this->getModule() . '/' . $action . 'View.php')) {
        throw new FrontControllerException('Page not found!');
    }

    //Sets $this->actionView to the path of the action View file
    $this->actionView = $this->pageDir . '/' . $this->getModule() . '/' . $action . 'View.php';

    //Sets path of the action View file into the registry
    $this->registry->set('actionView', $this->actionView);

    //Includes template file within which the action View file is included
    require_once $this->pageDir . '/default.tpl';
}
}

class Registry {

//Declaring variables
private $store;

//Class constructor
public function __construct() {}

//Sets registry variable
public function set($label, $object) {
    $this->store[$label] = $object;
}

//Gets registry variable    
public function get($label) {
    if(isset($this->store[$label])) {
        return $this->store[$label];
    }
    return false;
}

//Adds outside array of registry values to $this->store array
public function addRegistryArray($registryItems) {
    foreach ($registryItems as $key => $value) {
        $this->set($key, $value);
    }
}

//Returns registry array
public function getRegistryArray() {
    return $this->store;
}
}

class FrontControllerException extends Exception {

public function errorMessage($error) {

    //If throwExceptions is true, then the full exception is returned.
    $errorMessage = isset($error) ? $error : $this->getMessage();
    return $errorMessage;
}
}
```

Now, the problem... If I enter a URL with a nonexistent module (in the following example "BLAH")...

`http://example.com/index.php?module=BLAH&action=frontpage`

...I get not simply the error message "Page not found!" but the following error message...

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FrontControllerException' with message 'Page not found!' in /web/example.com/library/php/ControlArchitecture.php:45 Stack trace: #0 /web/example.com/index.php(30): FrontController->dispatch(false) #1 {main} thrown in /web/example.com/library/php/ControlArchitecture.php on line 45`

Any ideas on why I do not simply get the "Page not found!" message (instead of the uncaught exception)?  Any ideas on how to fix this behavior?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message actually says it all.

Wether the `FrontController->dispatch()` methods argument is `true` or `false` the exception will be thrown anyway..(if there's some *framework magic* going on, please let us know **which** framework you're using)

So make sure you're catching the exception where you're calling it:

```
/* ... */

  try {
    FrontController->dispatch(false);
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "Eception caught: " . $ex.getMessage();
  }

/* ... */
```

Update:

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) you can read about exceptions in PHP and how to catch them.

About the non-existent module issue:

```
$regex  = '/[^-_A-z0-9]+/';
$module = isset($_GET['module']) ? preg_replace($regex, '', $_GET['module']) : 'home';
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? preg_replace($regex, '', $_GET['action']) : 'frontpage';

$class = ucfirst($module) . 'Actions';
$file  = $this->pageDir . '/' . $module . '/' . $class . '.php';

if (!is_file($file)) {
    throw new FrontControllerException('Page not found!');
}
```

The `IF-Statement` only checks if the module file (Pattern: ModuleActions.php) in this case BLAHActions.php exists or not. Once it has thrown the exception, your call will the cancelled and it **won't** be *processed* anymore. (This means that it won't even continue to check the `Action` parameter)

About the non-existent action issue:

As of what I understand from the posted code, folowing method:

```
public function dispatchAction($action) {
    $actionMethod = 'do' . ucfirst($action);
    if (!method_exists($this, $actionMethod)) {
        throw new FrontControllerException('Page not found!');
    }
    $this->$actionMethod();
    $this->displayView($action);
}
```

makes calls to the required action (Pattern: doSomething) in this case doFrontPage isn't even called because your code throws an exception beforehand.

Calling a non existent action does not throw an unhandled exception, because it is `handled` in your FrontController->dispatch() method just after the module check:

```
try {
    //Trys the setModule method in the ActionController class
    $controller->setModule($module);

    /* The ActionController dispatchAction method checks if the method
     * exists, then runs the displayView function in the
     * ActionController class.
     */    
    $controller->dispatchAction($action);
}
catch(Exception $error) {

    /* An exception has occurred, and will be displayed if
     * $throwExceptions is set to true.
     */
    if($throwExceptions) {
        echo $error->errorMessage($error); //Full exception echoed
    } else {
        echo $error->errorMessage(null); //Simple error messaged echoed
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using a framework.  Also, where should your example code be placed in the above script?  I am not clear on what you are doing in your example.  I think perhaps I am not clear on what an "exception" is to start with.  And as a follow-up, why do I only get this full error message with a nonexistent module, but not with a nonexistent action or view?  (Thanks so much for your help!)

Comment: Answered your follow up question. I hope it makes at least SOME sense... (It's pretty late here ;-))